# Прогресс бар Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Нашел на просторах интернета такой прогресс бар `https://codepen.io/justincron/pen/rbIyD`
Но при попытке повторить его, допустим на `https://jsfiddle.net/`, отображается только текст, без самого бара

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">

      <p class="alert alert-success raised"><strong>Raised: $1,031.00</strong></p>

      <p class="alert alert-success goal"><strong>Goal: $4,200.00</strong></p>

      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


body {
  margin:50px;
}
.progress {
  position:relative;
  height:70px;
}
.raised {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:9px;
}
.goal {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дам формальный ответ, чтоб автор вопроса разобрался. Понимаю, что бывает очевидные вещи пролетают мимо глаз и превращаются в большую проблему, хоть и решение простое.
В вашем случае вы не установили подключение к фреймворку Bootstrap.

Добавьте в `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

И в самом низу `<body>` подключите необходимые скрипты:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

После этого всё будет отображаться и далее вы можете спокойно работать с данным фреймворком.
Надеюсь, что помог разобраться.

[Источник](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Изучите внимательно [компоненты](http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.3.1/components/progress/), тут есть такой прогрессбар. Для использования необходимого прогрессбара есть класс `.progress-bar-striped`

Пример:

```css
.progress {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь