# Как нарисовать линию с идникатором прогресса?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать эти линии-прогрессбары? Искал в интернете не нашёл.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: bootstrap имеет свои аналоги. progress bar

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

Comment: Вот ответ на Bootstrap: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950094/262779 Всё остальное делается стилями. Удачи!

Comment: Благодарю. Простите за тупой вопрос .

Comment: @Zak он не тупой, он просто начальный, все мы учились когда-то. Всё ок.

Comment: @L.F.C., опять бутстрап вместо десятка строк кода? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы с таким точно на Bootstrap не игрался, но показать вариант надо было, для кругозора. Тут народ во всю JS, SVG дает варианты, разве это легче для начинающего?

Comment: @L.F.C., у меня нет ни js, ни svg в ответе. И всего несколько строчек.

Comment: Всё, плюсы всем раздал, рабочий день закончен, можно и расслабится :))

Answer (score 5):

Вариантов тысячи, я использовал вариант `javascript` + `svg` как наиболее гибкий:

```js
[
  ['UI/UX DESIGN', 75, 'red'],
  ['WEB DEVELOPMENT', 90, 'green'],
  ['MARKETING', 65, 'blue'],
].forEach(el => document.body.append(progress(el)))

function progress(el) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let pathCfg = `class="fill" d="M0,5 L${el[1]*2},5" stroke="${el[2]}"`;
  div.innerHTML = `
    <div>${el[0]} ${el[1]}%</div>
    <svg viewbox="0 0 200 10" width="400" height="20">
      <path d="M0,5 L200,5" stroke="lightgray"></path>
      <path ${pathCfg} opacity="0.1" stroke-width="2"></path>
      <path ${pathCfg}></path>
    </svg>
  `;
  return div;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

path.fill {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Professional Skills</h2>
```

И согнул его чтобы показать гибкость =)

```js
[
  ['UI/UX DESIGN', 75, 'red'],
  ['WEB DEVELOPMENT', 90, 'green'],
  ['MARKETING', 65, 'blue'],
].forEach(el => document.body.append(progress(el)))

function progress(el) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let pathCfg = `class="fill" d="${sine(0, el[1])}" stroke="${el[2]}"`;
  div.innerHTML = `
    <div>${el[0]} ${el[1]}%</div>
    <svg viewbox="0 0 200 10" width="400" height="20">
      <path d="${sine(0, 200)}" stroke="lightgray"></path>
      <path ${pathCfg} opacity="0.1" stroke-width="2"></path>
      <path ${pathCfg}></path>
    </svg>
  `;
  return div;
}

function sine(x0, x1){
  let path = 'M0,5 ';
  for (let x = x0; x<x1; x+=1) 
    path += `L${x*2},${5+Math.sin(x/5)*3} `;
  return path;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

path{
  fill:none;
}

path.fill {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Professional Skills</h2>
```

Comment: Для начинающего верстальщика самое оно, понятнее некуда :)

Comment: Хм.. А тут снова svg...

Comment: @Qwertiy да, html + css это круто, но нет, но Вам +

Comment: Я там анимацию тоже могу приделать)

Comment: @Qwertiy да я понимаю, но гибкости меньше, вот я могу синусоидой её завернуть =)

Comment: Блин.. Я представил прогрессбар-змейку, бегающую за яблоками)))

Comment: @Qwertiy собрал синусоиду для прикола =)

Answer (score 4):

```css
div {
  height: 4px;
  background: silver;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Извини, когда писал не видел твой ответ. +1 Вот это вариант для начинающего, спасибо Qwertiy

Answer (score 4):

**Ванильный JS.** (Компонент)

```js
class Progress {
  constructor(node, width) {
    this.node = node;
    this.defaultWidth = width;
    
    if(!this.node) return;
    
    this.animation = this.animation.bind(this);
    
    this.label = this.node.querySelector(".progress__label-progress");
    this.bar = this.node.querySelector(".progress__bar-progress");
    
    this.interval = setInterval(this.animation, 1000);
  }
  
  animation() {
    this.defaultWidth >= 99 ? clearInterval(this.interval) : null;
    this.defaultWidth++;
    this.label.textContent = this.defaultWidth + "%";
    this.bar.style.width = this.defaultWidth + "%";
    
    if(this.defaultWidth < 99) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animation);
    }
  }
}

const root = document.querySelector(".progress");
var label = root.querySelector(".progress__label-progress").textContent.replace(/%/g, "");
var obj = new Progress(root, +label);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
}

.progress__label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.progress__bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.progress__bar-progress {
  width: 10%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #51aca7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__label">
      Marketing
      <span class="progress__label-progress">10%</span>
    </div>

    <div class="progress__bar">
      <div class="progress__bar-progress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотрится супер! +1

Answer (score 2):

Простой вариант на HTML и CSS

```js
$('input[type="number"]').on('change', function(){
  $('.progress-bar-edit .background')
    .css('width', $(this).val()+'%');
});
```

```css
.progress-bar, .progress-bar-edit {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.background {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #07f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="progress-bar-edit">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>

<input type="number" min="0" value="40" max="100" step="1">
```

Comment: HTML и CSS  +  JS! :))) +1. Учится ведь только ТС, какой JS? Для кругозора пусть варианты видит

Comment: Хм, возможно) Я привык к простоте, чтобы понятнее было))

Comment: так тут еще и JQuery, что может быть не приемлемо и все же указать бы в описании

Comment: Вариант тут только на HTML и CSS, как я указал выше, механика используется лишь для демонстрации работы прогресс бара. Даже если данный код кому-то нужен будет, то переписать его на JS - труда не составит.