# Как сверстать такую статистику?

Tags: html, css

Я уже год наверное просто избегаю этих статистик просто потому что не могу их верстать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как это правильнее сделать?Это тренировочный макет и здесь нет привязки к js или тому подобное.Нужно просто сверстать

Comment: Есть тег для этих целей [`<progress>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp) имя ему

Comment: Ответ на данный вопрос на сайте есть, воспользуйся поиском сайта

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963474/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/963482#963482

Answer (score 2):

Решений для этого может быть несколько. Я лишь показываю одно из таких решений. На мой взгляд оно хорошее.
Итак первым делом создаем просто блок (см код, это просто пример) создаете такой какой вам нужно, с конкретными значениями, которые необходимы вам.
2) Создаем внутри этого блока еще один блок, в данном случае на флексе, ставим ширину 100%
3) Внутри второго блока третий блок, пишем ширину в процентах такую, какую нужно. Выбираем цвет, эстетику, все дела.

Всё.

```css
.block {
    width: 540px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.stata100 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.shkala {
    width: 78%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><h2>Сделано на 78%</h2><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala"></div></div></div>
```

Второй вариант сделать градиентом, довольно простой:

```css
.grad {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #8BC34A 0% 78%, #FFEB3B 78% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grad"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так обычно делаю....с цветами  сами разберетесь

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .progressbar {
            height: 4px;
            position: relative;
            background: #5555552f;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .progressbar>span {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
            background-image: linear-gradient(center bottom,
                rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%,
                rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
            box-shadow:
                inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
                inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <span style="width: 30%"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```