# Как сделать полосу?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```css
.bars-line{
  background-color: red;
 height: 3px;
}
 
.bars-line > div{
  background-color: blue;
 height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-bars">
  <div class="bars">
    <div class="bars__title">
      УПРАВЛЕНИЕ ПРОДАЖАМИ В НЕДВИЖИМОСТИ<span>90%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bars-line">
      <div style='width: 88%;'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Как сделать полосу чтобы были 2 цвета ?
2. В зависимости от черного цвета менялся процент ?

Comment: тут 2 полосы,просто черная короче

Comment: @TEA здравствуйте тогда черная длинная, а серая короче

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963474/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/963482#963482

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Приветствую ссылку не посмотрел первый пункт сам решил посмотрите пожалуйста норм решение ?

Comment: @Leks вполне ничего, только почему 90 и 88 %?

Comment: Это тоже есть среди решений по ссылке

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  извините пропустил это и-за невнимательности

Comment: @Stranger in the Q можно любопытство проявить почему сменили картинку в профиле ?

Comment: @Leks захотелось =), прошлая уже давно стоит, поднадоела

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, богатым будете, я не узнал сначала)